# Unable to read pixels from a grayscale heightmap with WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to read the pixels of greyscale heightmap in order to store the height values later in a mesh, but whatever I do, I constantly read the same values rgba(0, 0, 0, 255).

**Note:** Color normal images are perfectly read.

**The image used:**

[image]

**Code I've written:**

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

gl.canvas.width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
gl.canvas.height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;

let vertexShaderSource = `
    attribute vec4 a_position;
 
    varying vec2 v_texturePos;
    
    void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(a_position.xy, 0, 1.0);
        
        v_texturePos = (a_position.xy+1.0)/2.0;
    }
`;

let fragmentShaderSource = `
    precision mediump float;
    
    uniform sampler2D u_heightmap;
    
    varying vec2 v_texturePos;
    
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_heightmap, v_texturePos);
    }
`;

function createShader(gl, type, source) {
    let shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    let success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
    if(success)
        return shader;
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
}

function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    let program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    let success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if(success)
        return program;
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
}

let mesh = [
    -1, -1, 0,
    -1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 0,

    1, 1, 0,
    1, -1, 0,
    -1, -1, 0
];

function drawScene(gl) {
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(mesh), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(attribPositionLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        let pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.canvas.width*gl.canvas.height*4/625);
        for(let g = 0; g < gl.canvas.width; g += 25) {
            for(let h = 0; h < gl.canvas.height; h += 25) {
                gl.readPixels(g, h, gl.canvas.width/25, gl.canvas.height/25, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
            }
        }
        console.log(pixels);
    }

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

let attribPositionLoc;
let frameBuffer;
let texture, frameTexture;

function resize(gl) {
    let realToCSSPixels = window.devicePixelRatio;

    let displayWidth  = Math.floor(gl.canvas.clientWidth  * realToCSSPixels);
    let displayHeight = Math.floor(gl.canvas.clientHeight * realToCSSPixels);

    if (gl.canvas.width  !== displayWidth ||
        gl.canvas.height !== displayHeight) {

        gl.canvas.width  = displayWidth;
        gl.canvas.height = displayHeight;
    }
}

let img = document.createElement("img");
img.crossOrigin = "null";
img.src = "http://localhost:8000/heightmap?filename=terrain.jpg";
img.addEventListener("load", startWebGL.bind(this, gl));

function startWebGL(gl) {
    resize(gl);
    let vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
    let fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);

    let program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

    gl.useProgram(program);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    frameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

    frameTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture, 0);

    attribPositionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

    let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attribPositionLoc);

    drawScene(gl);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear what this code is trying to do

```
let pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.canvas.width*gl.canvas.height*4/625);
for(let g = 0; g < gl.canvas.width; g += 25) {
    for(let h = 0; h < gl.canvas.height; h += 25) {
        gl.readPixels(g, h, gl.canvas.width/25, gl.canvas.height/25, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    }
}
console.log(pixels);
```

What does dividing by 625 do? On top of that you only print the last result. If you want read the entire canvas it's just

```
let pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.canvas.width*gl.canvas.height*4);
gl.readPixels(g, h, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

In any case if I change the URL for the image to something that can be loaded while on stack overflow I see the expected values. Looking at your image since you're only reading at 25x25 area and you're only printing the last 25x25 area since your `console.log` is outside the loop I'm guessing your reading a black corner of the image.

Also since you're stepping by 25, if your canvas is not a multiple of 25 then you'll read off the edge, past the end of the canvas. Reading off the edge always produces 0,0,0,0.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

gl.canvas.width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
gl.canvas.height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;

let vertexShaderSource = `
    attribute vec4 a_position;
 
    varying vec2 v_texturePos;
    
    void main() {
        gl_Position = vec4(a_position.xy, 0, 1.0);
        
        v_texturePos = (a_position.xy+1.0)/2.0;
    }
`;

let fragmentShaderSource = `
    precision mediump float;
    
    uniform sampler2D u_heightmap;
    
    varying vec2 v_texturePos;
    
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_heightmap, v_texturePos);
    }
`;

function createShader(gl, type, source) {
    let shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    let success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
    if(success)
        return shader;
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    gl.deleteShader(shader);
}

function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) {
    let program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    let success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if(success)
        return program;
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    gl.deleteProgram(program);
}

let mesh = [
    -1, -1, 0,
    -1, 1, 0,
    1, 1, 0,

    1, 1, 0,
    1, -1, 0,
    -1, -1, 0
];

function drawScene(gl) {
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(mesh), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(attribPositionLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        let pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.canvas.width*gl.canvas.height*4/625);
        for(let g = 0; g < gl.canvas.width; g += 25) {
            for(let h = 0; h < gl.canvas.height; h += 25) {
                gl.readPixels(g, h, gl.canvas.width/25, gl.canvas.height/25, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
            }
        }
        console.log(pixels);
    }

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}

let attribPositionLoc;
let frameBuffer;
let texture, frameTexture;

function resize(gl) {
    let realToCSSPixels = window.devicePixelRatio;

    let displayWidth  = Math.floor(gl.canvas.clientWidth  * realToCSSPixels);
    let displayHeight = Math.floor(gl.canvas.clientHeight * realToCSSPixels);

    if (gl.canvas.width  !== displayWidth ||
        gl.canvas.height !== displayHeight) {

        gl.canvas.width  = displayWidth;
        gl.canvas.height = displayHeight;
    }
}

let img = document.createElement("img");
img.crossOrigin = "null";
// img.src = "http://localhost:8000/heightmap?filename=terrain.jpg";
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png";
img.addEventListener("load", startWebGL.bind(this, gl));

function startWebGL(gl) {
    resize(gl);
    let vertexShader = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource);
    let fragmentShader = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource);

    let program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

    gl.useProgram(program);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LESS);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    frameBuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

    frameTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameTexture, 0);

    attribPositionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

    let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attribPositionLoc);

    drawScene(gl);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, misunderstood I that the function gl.readPixels was actually reading square blocks instead of pixel by pixel. And because I forgot that the image was black in corners, thus all the debugging went in vain. Thanks gman.